# Sort data in SQL Server based on parent child relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I store details about the chapters, I have to show data in following order of Table of Index

> 1. Chapter One
>
>    1.1 Chapter One Page 1
>
>    1.2 Chapter One Page 2
> 2. Chapter Two
>
>    2.1 Chapter Two Page 1
>
>    2.2 Chapter Two Page 2
> 3. Chapter Three
>
>    Title One
>
>    Title Two
>
>    Title Three
>
>    3.1 Chapter Three Page 1
>
>    3.2 Chapter Three Page 2
>
>    3.3 Chapter Three Page 3

We can insert data in database in sorted or un-sorted order. But data should show in a sorted order based on pageOrder of Parent and Child pages

I have set up SQL Fiddle but for some reason I am not able to save SQL. Below you will find fiddle link and details

```
CREATE TABLE [Book]
(
     [id] int, 
     [Chapter] varchar(20), 
     [PageOrder] int, 
     [parentID] int
);

INSERT INTO [Book] ([id], [Chapter], [PageOrder],  [parentID])
VALUES
    ('1', 'Chapter One', 1, 0),
    ('2', 'Chapter Two', 2, 0),
    ('3', 'Chapter Three', 3, 0),
    ('4', 'Chapter Four', 4, 0),
    ('5', 'Chapter Five', 5, 0),
    ('6', 'Chapter One Page 1', 1, 1),
    ('7', 'Chapter One Page 2', 2, 1),
    ('8', 'Chapter One Page 3', 3, 1),
    ('9', 'Chapter One Page 4', 4, 1),
    ('10', 'Chapter Two Page 1', 1, 2),
    ('11', 'Chapter Two Page 3', 3, 2),
    ('12', 'Chapter Two Page 2', 2, 2),
    ('13', 'Chapter Three Tite 1', 0, 3),
    ('14', 'Chapter Three Tite 2', 0, 3),
    ('15', 'Chapter Three Tite 3', 0, 3),
    ('16', 'Chapter Three Page 2', 2, 3),
    ('17', 'Chapter Three Page 3', 3, 3),
    ('18', 'Chapter Three Page 1', 1, 3);

WITH CTE(ID, parentID, Chapter, PageOrder, Depth, SortCol) AS  
( 
    SELECT 
        ID, parentID, Chapter, PageOrder, 0, 
        CAST(ID AS varbinary(max)) 
    FROM Book 
    WHERE parentID = 0 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        d.ID, d.parentID, d.Chapter, d.PageOrder, p.Depth + 1, 
        CAST(SortCol + CAST(d.ID AS binary(4)) AS varbinary(max)) 
    FROM Book AS d 
    JOIN CTE AS p ON d.parentID = p.ID 
) 
SELECT 
    ID, parentID, Chapter, PageOrder, Depth, 
    REPLICATE('--', Depth) + Chapter as PageName 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY SortCol
```

This CTE query is sorting data but it child pages are not properly sorted child pages show up in sort order in which they where saved in database

SqlFiddle Link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9770a/1

Comment: For ( '12','Chapter Two Page 2', 2, 1) record parent id is 2 or 1 can u confirm? because you are page order is 2 under chapter 2 so.

Comment: Yes You are correct, event changing it tow 2 wont make any change in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PageOrder` instead of `ID` to build `SortCol`, also cast to `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `VARBINARY(MAX)`:

```
WITH CTE(ID, parentID, Chapter, PageOrder, Depth, SortCol)  AS  ( 
  SELECT ID, parentID, Chapter,PageOrder, 0, 
         CAST(PageOrder AS varchar(max)) 
  FROM Book 
  WHERE parentID = 0 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT d.ID, d.parentID, d.Chapter, d.PageOrder, p.Depth + 1, 
  CAST(SortCol + CAST(d.PageOrder AS varchar(max)) AS varchar(max)) 
  FROM Book AS d 
  JOIN CTE AS p ON d.parentID = p.ID 
)   
SELECT ID, parentID, Chapter, PageOrder, Depth, SortCol,
       REPLICATE('--', Depth) + Chapter as PageName 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY SortCol, Chapter
```

Additionally `Chapter` column is used to sort chapters having the same `PageOrder` and belonging to the same tree level.

[**Demo here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9770a/2)

Answer (score 2):

The Complete Solution like

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
     SELECT p.CategoryID
       , p.Category_Name
       , p.IsParent
       , p.ParentID
       , p.Active
       , p.Sort_Order AS Primary_Sort_Order
       , CASE WHEN p.IsParent = 0 THEN (SELECT Sort_Order FROM tbl_Category WHERE 
     CategoryID = p.ParentID) ELSE p.Sort_Order END AS Secondary_Sort_Order
      FROM tbl_Category p
    ) x
    ORDER BY Secondary_Sort_Order,
            CASE WHEN ParentID = 0 THEN CategoryID ELSE ParentID END,

            CASE WHEN ParentID = 0 THEN 0 ELSE Primary_Sort_Order END,
         Primary_Sort_Order ASC
```

Hope It helps....!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, REPLICATE('--', CASE WHEN parentID > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + Chapter AS PageName 
FROM Book 
ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(parentID,0), id), parentID, PageOrder
```